# Any known issues with msxml3.dll on Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, msxml3, rds

I'm trying to migrate a VB6 business object, which uses RDS to be accessed, from a Windows 2000 to a Windows 2003 server environment.  I've made no changes to the app, nor the calling app, but I am getting an error code 440 Automation Error when the code execution reaches the point of parsing the XML data that the object is supposed to process (SAXXMLReader). The app uses msxml3.dll, and the dll is installed on the server.  Does anyone know if there are known issues between msxml3 and win2003 server?

Or any other suggestions?

Here's the code that calls the reader:

```
Set reader = New SAXXMLReader
Set contentHandler = New mBL_ContentHandlerImpl
Set errorHandler = New mBL_ErrorHandlerImpl

contentHandler.rsBatch = m_rsBatch
contentHandler.rsDocument = m_rsDocument

Set reader.contentHandler = contentHandler 
Set reader.errorHandler = errorHandler     

reader.parse (sData)
```

I don't know what value putting code here is going to have.  The implementation of the SAX reader content handler is rather large and unwieldy.  The problem isn't in the code, I don't believe, since this app works fine on Win 2k server.

Comment: Can you paste in sample code where the error is being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to have nothing to do with any issue between msxml 3 and Windows 2003.  The problem was idiosyncratic to the application in that there needed to be a registry entry available that was not there.  This application is not well documented, and so a lot had to discovered by close inspection of a LOT of code.